# CVAT annotation tool. Including own DL model

Tags: image-processing, annotations, annotation-processing

I work with CVAT, but I want to include my own trained model for auto segmentation. When I try to find how to do it in the new version I did not find any tutorial or explanation, even this situation does not explain in the documentation.

Comment: Not sure if it is applicable to your case... perhaps this can point you in the right direction: https://github.com/openvinotoolkit/cvat/discussions/3074.

Comment: Nik O'Lai Thank you

Comment: This helped us - https://openvinotoolkit.github.io/cvat/docs/manual/advanced/serverless-tutorial/